# How to create an event handler for a range slider?

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm trying to get a range slider to work but I can't.
How do I add an event handler so when the user chooses a value my code reads that value. Right now its value is always `1`.

I would like to do this using pure Javascript.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slider">
    <input class="bar" type="range" id="rangeinput" min="1" max="25" value="1" onchange="rangevalue.value=value"/>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <output id="rangevalue">1</output>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeinput").value;
var buttonInput = document.getElementById("btn");

if (buttonInput.addEventListener) {
    buttonInput.addEventListener("click", testtest, false);
}
else if (buttonInput.attachEvent) {
    buttonInput.attachEvent('onclick', testtest);
}

function testtest(e) {
    if (rangeInput > 0 && rangeInput < 5) {
        alert("First");
    } else {
        alert("Second");
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g9ZUs/2/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Single Read

The problem is that you're only reading the value once (at startup), instead of reading it every time the event occurs:

```
// this stores the value at startup (which is why you're always getting 1)
var rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeinput").value;
```

You should be reading the value in the handler instead:

```
function testtest(e) {
    // read the value from the slider:
    var value = document.getElementById("rangeinput").value;
    // now compare:
    if (value > 0 && value < 5) {
        alert("First");
    } else {
        alert("Second");
    }
}
```

Or to rewrite your code:

```
var rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeinput");
var buttonInput = document.getElementById("btn");

if (buttonInput.addEventListener) {
    buttonInput.addEventListener("click", testtest, false);
}
else if (buttonInput.attachEvent) {
    buttonInput.attachEvent('onclick', testtest);
}

function testtest(e) {
    var value = rangeInput.value;
    if (value > 0 && value < 5) {
        alert("First");
    } else {
        alert("Second");
    }
}
```

### Updating rangevalue

It also looks like you want to update the output element with the value of the range.  What you're currently doing is referring to the element by id:

```
onchange="rangevalue.value=value"
```

However, as far as I know, this isn't standard behavior; you can't refer to elements by their id alone; you have to retrieve the element and then set the value via the DOM.

Might I suggest that you add a change listener via javascript:

```
rangeInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("rangevalue").textContent = rangeInput.value;
}, false);
```

Of course, you'll have to update the code to use `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` depending on the browsers that you want to support; this is where [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) really becomes helpful.

Comment: Thanks it works but for a strange reason it only works with Chrome.

Comment: @KalPetros - I've updated the answer to address updating the output.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `mouseup` event for that.

```
var rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeinput");

rangeInput.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    if (this.value > 0 && this.value < 5) {
        alert("First");
    } else{
        alert("Second");
    }
});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnYjY/1**

Comment: will this also work if the user changes the value with the arrow keys?

Comment: @PhilipEagles probably not. onkeyup() would probably work for that though.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the FORMs `oninput` method:

```
<form oninput="result.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">
  <input type="range" name="b" value="50" />100 +
  <input type="number" name="a" value="10" /> =
  <output name="result"></output>
</form>
```

This has an advantage over `onclick/onmouseup` because it handles the case where the slider is moved using the keyboard (tab to the input and use the arrow keys)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `oninput` event.

**HTML Codes:**

```html
<div id="slider">
    <input class="bar" type="range" id="range-input" min="1" max="25" value="1"/>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <output id="range-value">1</output>
</div>
<button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

**Javascript scripts**

```js
(function() {
 var rangeInput = document.getElementById("range-input")
 var rangeValue = document.getElementById("range-value")
 var button = document.getElementById("btn")
 
 // Show alert message when button clicked
 button.onclick = testTest
 
 function testTest() {
   let value = rangeInput.value
   if(value > 0 && value < 5) {
      alert("first")
      return true
   }
     alert("second")
     return false
 }
 
 // Print the range value to the output
 rangeInput.oninput = rangeOutput
 
 function rangeOutput() {
   rangeValue.innerText = rangeInput.value
 }

})()
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4st0o25p/1/)**

**UPDATE 2021**

**Another option is to use the input event handler i.e. eventTarget.addEventListener("input", alert("Hello World"), though this event handler is the same with oninput, the difference having we can use addEventListener**

Comment: Update: Another option is to use the `input` event handler i.e. `eventTarget.addEventListener("input", alert("Hello World")`, though this event handler is the same with `oninput`, the difference having we can use `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function range()
    {
//the simplest way i found
    var p = document.getElementById('weight');
    var res = document.getElementById('rangeval');
    res.innerHTML=p.value+ " Lbs";
    }
</script>

  <label for="weight">Your weight in lbs:</label>
  <input name="weight" type="range" id="weight" max="500" min="0" value="75" onChange="range()" onKeyUp="range()">
  <span id="rangeval"></span>
```