# Javascript if slider value = 20 , display text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a slider using html and CSS which displays its value on change. I styled it using CSS using the `<style>` tag. I then went on to making the value display text. I want to display "Starter" when the slider hits 20.
I don't know what I am doing wrong and why this isn't working for me. I would like to use the most user-friendly version of this. If possible, please explain what I did wrong.

```
<html>
<style>
 input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 100%;
   height: 25px;
   border: 1px solid;
   background-color: #0066FF;
}
   input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: #FFF;

}
 </style>
 </html>
 <form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">

 <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" step="20" value="0">
 <div align="center" style="font-size:25px;"><output name="amount"     for="rangeInput">0</output></div>

 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeInput").value
 if(rangeInput = 20){
 text = "starter"
 }
```

How can i get my slider to RESET on value 0?

at the moment, if i go from 20 to 0, it stays displaying Starter , i would like it to remove that. Is this possible?

Comment: `<html>` tag is the root element that includes the rest of your code. you dont just close it in the middle of your document. best advice i can give you, is to follow the tutorials [Here](http://www.w3schools.com) first.

Answer (score 1):

you need '==' instead of '=' with your if statement

```
var rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeInput").value
 if(rangeInput == 20){
 text = "starter"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this question, as well: [Range Slider Event Handler Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625334/range-slider-event-handler-javascript)

You're going to want to look into [event listeners](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)-- you want to have a listener bound to the slider so that when the user changes the value, your code can respond accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen for `onchange` event. Also, you need to use `==` instead of `=` to compare values. The following code should work -

```js
function updateValue() {
  var rangeInput = document.getElementById("rangeInput").value
  if (rangeInput == 20) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 'starter'
  } else {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = ''
  }
}
```

```css
input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #0066FF;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<form oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">

  <input type="range" id="rangeInput" name="rangeInput" step="20" value="0" onchange="updateValue()">
  <div align="center" style="font-size:25px;">
    <output name="amount" for="rangeInput">0</output>
  </div>
</form>

<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: how can i reset a variable? Say for example i used the code:

    var starter = "Hello World"
    if (starter == 20){
     document.write(starter)
    }

Because im using a slider, when that (staretrs) value =20, it should display a that "hello world" for me, but when it goes to it for a 2nd time, it just pastes it underneath, How can i reset the function? 

Prefered if i could embed it into an existing function, so at the start of the function activating, it clears the page and pastes what i need it to see